# get_object_or_404, Page not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

Я только начинаю изучать django, подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем связана ошибка Page not found (404)
No AkpVictim matches the given query?

Views.py

```
def victim(request):
    error = ''
    id_incidents = request.session.get('Id_Incidents', 'ничего не передано')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AkpVictimForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and 'next' in request.POST:
            just_created = form.save(commit=False)
            just_created.An_Foreign_Field = get_object_or_404(AkpVictim, Id_Incidents=id_incidents)
            just_created.save()
            return redirect('main:group')
        elif 'back' in request.POST:
            return redirect('main:incident')
        else:
            error = 'Форма заполнена некорректно'

    form = AkpVictimForm()
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
        'id_incidents': id_incidents,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/victim.html', data)
```

Urls.py

```
app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.start, name="start"),
    path('incident', views.incident, name="incident"),
    path('victim', views.victim, name="victim"),
    path('group', views.Groups.as_view(), name='group'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_object_or_404` как и следует из названия возвращает объект, а если он не найден, выкидывает эксепшн 404 страница не найдена. В вашем случае в AkpVictim нет записи с Id_Incidents=id_incidents.
Если вы предполагаете что в сессии может не быть id_incidents, то вместо `get_object_or_404` вам надо получать все `AkpVictim.objects.filter(Id_Incidents=id_incidents)` и в зависимости от результата (найдена ли запись), обрабатывать запрос

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне помогли

Comment: не за что. не забывайте ставить отметку о том что ваш вопрос решен